# Merge two XML files with reference ID

Tags: php, xml

I have two XMLs, and could somebody help me how to merge it in one XML with PHP.
Both XMLs have same . I need to merge it with all nodes, refering data with same "ProductCode".

Content XML1:

```
<Table>
<ProductCode>0352097</ProductCode>
<ProductName>Product Name</ProductName>
<ProductType>Product Type</ProductType>
<Brand>Brand</Brand>
<PartNo>Q3960A</PartNo>
</Table>
```

Content XML2:

```
<Table>
<ProductCode>0120392</ProductCode>
<ProductListPrice>XXX</ProductListPrice>
<ProductDiscount>YYYY</ProductDiscount>
<ProductPartnerPrice>ZZZ</ProductPartnerPrice>
</Table>
```

I want to acomplish this:

```
<Table>
<ProductCode>0352097</ProductCode>
<ProductName>Product Name</ProductName>
<ProductType>Product Type</ProductType>
<Brand>Brand</Brand>
<PartNo>Q3960A</PartNo>
<ProductListPrice>XXX</ProductListPrice>
<ProductDiscount>YYYY</ProductDiscount>
<ProductPartnerPrice>ZZZ</ProductPartnerPrice>
</Table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOM allows you to import nodes from one document into another and with Xpath you can select the nodes.

```
$target = new DOMDocument();
$target->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$target->loadXml($xml1);
$targetXpath = new DOMXpath($target);

$source = new DOMDocument();
$source->loadXml($xml2);
$sourceXpath = new DOMXpath($source);
foreach ($targetXpath->evaluate('//Table') as $tableNode) {
  $productCode = $targetXpath->evaluate('string(ProductCode)', $tableNode);
  foreach ($sourceXpath->evaluate('//Table[ProductCode="'.$productCode.'"]/*[not(self::ProductCode)]') as $node) {
    $tableNode->appendChild(
      $target->importNode($node, TRUE)
    );
  }
}

$target->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $target->saveXml();
```

`DOMDocument::importNode()` copies a node including all its properties (tag name, namespace), attributes and descendant nodes.

Comment: Thank you, but is there a right way to call XML like: `$target->loadXml('GetProductslist.aspx.xml');` or is something else, because I get log error for those lines. Thanks

Comment: Works :), thank you a lot. I just put $target->load('GetProductslist.aspx.xml'); and on top header('Content-type:  text/xml');

Comment: Yes `DOMDocument::loadXml()` is for XML strings, `DOMDocument::load()` for XML files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `simplexml_load_string` function and `SimpleXMLElement` class to handle XML.

**Snippet**

```
$xml1 = '<Table>
<ProductCode>0352097</ProductCode>
<ProductName>Product Name</ProductName>
<ProductType>Product Type</ProductType>
<Brand>Brand</Brand>
<PartNo>Q3960A</PartNo>
</Table>';

$xml2 = '<Table>
<ProductCode>0120392</ProductCode>
<ProductListPrice>XXX</ProductListPrice>
<ProductDiscount>YYYY</ProductDiscount>
<ProductPartnerPrice>ZZZ</ProductPartnerPrice>
</Table>';

//Converting to array
$xml1 = (array) simplexml_load_string($xml1);
$xml2 = (array) simplexml_load_string($xml2);
array_shift($xml2); //Removing Product Code From Second XML
//Merging Together
$resultAsArray =  array_merge($xml1, $xml2);
//Flipping array
$flipped = array_flip($resultAsArray);

//Converting Back To The XML
$resultXML = new SimpleXMLElement('<Table/>');
array_walk($flipped, array ($resultXML, 'addChild'));
print $resultXML->asXML();
```

***Output***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Table>
   <ProductCode>0352097</ProductCode>
   <ProductName>Product Name</ProductName>
   <ProductType>Product Type</ProductType>
   <Brand>Brand</Brand>
   <PartNo>Q3960A</PartNo>
   <ProductListPrice>XXX</ProductListPrice>
   <ProductDiscount>YYYY</ProductDiscount>
   <ProductPartnerPrice>ZZZ</ProductPartnerPrice>
</Table>
```

Check Demo [Here](https://3v4l.org/95VhB)

Reference: 
[simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) 
[SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php)

Comment: @PozitivneVijesti  Have you check demo??? https://3v4l.org/95VhB, want to merge data based on `ProductCode` ?

Answer (score 0):

Using SimpleXML to process the documents is the easiest option.  This assumes you have two lists of parts to merge and uses XPath to find the matching data in the first document with the part to update with from the second document.  It then just copies everything (except the ProductCode) into the base document.

So with some simple test data...

```
$xml1 = "<Products>
    <Table>
        <ProductCode>0352097</ProductCode>
        <ProductName>Product Name</ProductName>
        <ProductType>Product Type</ProductType>
        <Brand>Brand</Brand>
        <PartNo>Q3960A</PartNo>
    </Table>
    <Table>
        <ProductCode>0352098</ProductCode>
        <ProductName>Product Name2</ProductName>
        <ProductType>Product Type2</ProductType>
        <Brand>Brand2</Brand>
        <PartNo>Q3960A2</PartNo>
    </Table>
</Products>";

$xml2 = "<Products>
    <Table>
        <ProductCode>0352097</ProductCode>
        <ProductListPrice>p1</ProductListPrice>
        <ProductDiscount>pp1</ProductDiscount>
        <ProductPartnerPrice>1</ProductPartnerPrice>
    </Table>
    <Table>
        <ProductCode>0352098</ProductCode>
        <ProductListPrice>p2</ProductListPrice>
        <ProductDiscount>pp2</ProductDiscount>
        <ProductPartnerPrice>2</ProductPartnerPrice>
    </Table>
</Products>";
```

The code comes down to...

```
$base = simplexml_load_string($xml1);
$add = simplexml_load_string($xml2);

foreach ( $add->Table as $addData )    {
    // Find the corresponding element (take the first match using [0])
    $addTo = $base->xpath("//Table[ProductCode='{$addData->ProductCode}']")[0];
    foreach ( $addData->children() as $name => $value )    {
        if ($name != "ProductCode") {
            $addTo->addChild($name, $value);
        }
    }
}

echo $base->asXML();
```

Note that this only works with flat structures, if you have any attributes or more complex data structures, you would need to have a different solution.

Comment: I cant call this script. `<?php


$base = simplexml_load_string('GetProductslist.aspx.xml');
$add = simplexml_load_string('GetProductsPriceList.aspx.xml');

foreach ( $add->Table as $addData )    {
    // Find the corresponding element (take the first match using [0])
    $addTo = $base->xpath("//Table[ProductCode='{$addData->ProductCode}']")[0];
    foreach ( $addData->children() as $name => $value )    {
        if ($name != "ProductCode") {
            $addTo->addChild($name, $value);
        }
    }
}


echo $base->asXML();

?>`

Comment: Using `simplexml_load_string()` works with strings for the data, if you wanted to load files - you need to use `simplexml_load_file()`